# How to not wait for USB to become active?

Tags: arduino-nano, bootloader

*EDIT: My original question was a bit "off" since the Arduino Nano I was using appeared to be faulty. This edited question is based on my other Arduino Nano which is working.*

When I plug my Arduino into the PC, it keeps blinking it's LED until I open the Serial Monitor.

After opening the serial monitor the Arduino will start to execute my code.

How can I get my Arduino to "not wait on a connection", or simply put, start whenever it receives power.

I believe it's the bootloader which somehow doesn't time-out (I'm not sure if that's how the bootloader works).

The code below (though I don't see why this would make it hang until a connection):

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(256000);
  Serial.write("Restart");
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // say what you got:
    startSend();
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
    stopSend();
  }else{
    startSend();
    Serial.println("I'm still standing");
    stopSend();
    delay(400);
  }
}
```

(Code is only for testing purposes)

Comment: It's likely people will need to see your code (sketch) in your question in order to help.

Comment: I've just changed board, and it seems to work a lot better. But it still seems  Arduino won't start until I open the serial monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you post your code this answer may not apply.  But, guessing, you may benefit from changing your code from:

```
loop()
{
 data = Serial.read();
 // Do other sutff
}
```

To something like this:

```
loop()
{
 if(Serial.available() > 1)
 {
  data = Serial.read();
 }
 // Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it appeared to be some vague hardware problem. My CH340G board runs fine, the FTDI (from China) doesn't, I think it's a fake.

Comment: And, the code won't upload while I have it connected to the MAX485, I think it might "drain the bits".